# Microsoft SpeechSynthesizer (TTS) Voice Crackle

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

When using Microsoft [SpeechSynthesizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx) voices sometimes crackle, are fuzy...

```
// Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

// Configure the audio output. 
synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

// Speak a string.
synth.Speak("This example demonstrates a basic use of Speech Synthesizer");
```

I assume it is related to CPU usage. But it happend on powerfull computer too. Is there any best practices or workaroud ?

Comment: Which voice are you using?

Comment: I'm testing Virginie (FR) 16Khz from Scansoft available everywhere on the net

Comment: It might be something related to the voice itself.  Does this reproduce with different voices?

Comment: It works with 2 other voices with low speech rate I assume it is caused by speech rate + cpu usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the [rate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.rate.aspx) downwards, until the crackling disappears.

Comment: It seems to help and it's also cpu related